# Использовать Word OLEObject в безопасном режиме

Tags: delphi, com, office-interop

Есть сервер, на котором установлен MS Office и некая надстройка к нему. Систематически эта надстройка мешает работе MS Word, показывая сообщения об ошибке. И мешает программной работе с Word.

Удалить надстройку нельзя, отключить тоже (какой бы кривой она ни была - она используется заказчиком).

Требуется: попробовать отключить надстройки локально (в пределах своего процесса, работающего с Офисом).

Отключение надстройки следующим образом влияет глобально:

```
App:=CreateOleObject('Word.Application');

for i := 1 to App.COMAddIns.Count do
begin
  AddIn:=App.COMAddIns.Item(i);
  mm1.Lines.Add(AddIn.Description + '  ' + AddIn.ProgId);
  if AddIn.Connect then
    mm1.Lines.Add('    connected')
  else
    mm1.Lines.Add('    disconnected');
  AddIn.Connect:=False; // глушим надстройку, изменения применяются "для всех"
end;
```

Есть возможность запуска офисных приложений [в безопасном режиме](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-Office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-Windows-PC-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72). Но это через командную строку, отдельным процессом.

Вопрос: можно ли сделать что-то подобное (запустить экземпляр Word / Excel) без надстроек, программно, чтобы использовать как OLE-объект?

Comment: А отключение предупреждений и событий не помогает?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci это как? Можно ссылку?

Answer (score 0):

Этот код инициализации использовался для работы с Excel, но думаю для Word тоже подойдет.

```
L:=LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT;
App:=CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
App.ConnectKind:=ckNewInstance;
App.AutoQuit:=True;
App.DisplayAlerts[L]:=False;  // отключаем предупреждения
App.Visible[L]:=False;
// Отключаем реакцию на события, чтобы ускорить обработку
App.Application.EnableEvents:=False;
App.Connect;
```

Comment: Возможно, здесь использовались TWord/TExcelApplication? для App: OleVariant говорит, что ConnectKind, AutoQuit, EnableEvents не найдены.

Comment: Нет, `TWordApplication.Application` тоже не имеет свойства `EnableEvents`. Сайты эмбы в дауне, онлайн-хелп недоступен, к сожалению... приходится вот так, опытным путем...

Comment: Да, в оригинале было `TExcelApplication`.

Comment: Сейчас попробую проверить только с DisplayAlerts = False, по результатам отпишусь.

Comment: Прошу прощения за задержку - проверка идет именно у заказчика, у меня такой "тестовый стенд" не развернуть. Увы, DisplayAlerts = False не помогло...

Comment: А вы не пробовали использовать TWordApplication вместо OleVariant?

Comment: В тестовых примерах - да, пробовал.  Первый тест передавался по вашему коду, с учетом, что App был типа TWordApplication и у него нет свойства EnableEvents. В заключительных же тестах мы убедились, что ошибки и очень мешающие сообщения о них выводятся именно внутренностями надстройки. Которая не собирается считаться с DisplayAlerts = False.

Comment: 'ConnectKind' у TWordApplication есть? Если указать там 'ckNewInstance' то будет создан отдельный новый процесс (даже если ворд уже запущен у пользователя), в котором можно попробовать отключить надстройки, сделать то, что вам нужно и включить все обратно как было. Пробовали такой вариант?

Comment: `ConnectKind` есть. Но увы - программное отключение настроек на уже запущенном экземпляре применяется не к нему, а глобально, о чем я писал в вопросе.

Comment: А что если включать надстройки обратно, после выполнения работы? Насколько глобально отключение? В пределах всей системы или только текущего пользователя? Если только пользователя, то может быть можно завести на машине специального пользователя и выполнять задачи под его учеткой?

Comment: Этот вопрос прорабатывался сразу. Даже если отключение распространяется только на текущего пользователя - отключение надстроек повлияет на его работу, поскольку используется несколько приложений и в некоторых надстройка нужна. Отдельного пользователя ... увы, нет. Сделать отдельный поток для экспорта и в нем что-то типа ImpersonateLoggedOnUser можно, но проблематично. Пока оставили проблему as-is, клиент согласился что это не наша загвоздка и живет с сообщениями об ошибках.